# Potential bug in as.list.Date (the R programming language)

Tags: r, list, date, type-conversion

It seems to me that the following should be true for any vector type.

```
all(names(as.list(x)) == names(x))
```

I say so because I tried with several atomic types and because it is reasonable.

But with Date:

```
> dd = as.Date(c("1950-01-01", "2050-01-01" ))
> names(dd)  = c("from", "to")
> dd
        from           to 
"1950-01-01" "2050-01-01" 
> as.list(dd)
[[1]]
        from 
"1950-01-01" 

[[2]]
          to 
"2050-01-01"
```

What do you think? R bug or bug in my thinking?

PS: I have a workaround, thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close as primarily opinion based, since only an R-core member could confirm whether or not this is a bug.

Comment: you might do better with this on `r-devel@r-project.org` ...

Comment: ... with a reproducible example.

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? We do not see an object named`dd`:  `all(names(as.list(as.Date("1970-01-01"))) == names(as.Date("1970-01-01")) ); #[1] TRUE`

Comment: I would point out that @piccolbo is highly skilled at R and unlikely to be posting frivolous bug-queries.

Comment: This doesn't work with factors either; do you consider those an atomic type? I'm not sure it's a bug so much as it's just not the behavior you expected.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich My previous SO post was a bug report and a core member confirmed it. It was also about the Date class

Comment: @BenBolker I don't have much success with r-devel. I get redirected to r-help where I get ripleyed. You are free to use that mailing list. I get more milage here.

Comment: @Pascal good point, fixed

Comment: @MrFlick is.atomic(factor()) is the answer. Good point, so my invariant fails for factors as well. That answers the question, if you want to take the credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example also seems to fail with factors as well

```
x <- factor(c("one","two"))
names(x) <- c("a","b")
x

#   a   b 
# one two 
# Levels: one two

as.list(x)

# [[1]]
#   a 
# one 
# Levels: one two
# 
# [[2]]
#   b 
# two 
# Levels: one two
```

which are also atomic types

```
is.atomic(x)
# [1] TRUE
```

so this just doesn't happen with dates. That being the case, I'm reluctant to call it a bug since I don't believe any particular behavior are far as the names go is documented anywhere. However it is unfortunate that the results are inconsistent compared to numeric or character vectors.